# In a stable medieval fantasy population, what should be the yearly birth rate per 1,000 people?

Tags: humans, medieval, population, low-fantasy

For a human or human-like stable, small settlement population, living in medieval fantasy, how many yearly births per 1,000 inhabitants are expected?

Assuming:

1. There is no major epidemic.
2. There are no wars or invasions.
3. Starvation is not a problem.
4. Magical healing for moderate illness and accidents is expensive but not out of reach of the peasants (minor ones don't require magic, major ones may have treatment but are unaffordable).
5. The population is stable over a long period of time. The rate of death, birth plus migration even out.

Comment: There's an infinite number of ways to solve the equation (Births+Migration) - Deaths = 0.  They can be whatever you want so long as they balance out.  Judging by your description, it sounds kinda like the current US.  We have pretty good, but pricey healthcare, no wars, no epidemics, and starvation isn't a problem.

Comment: "medieval fantasy", even with stated conditions, is very poorly defined. It may range from very realistic medieval world, with high infant (and adult) mortality to fairy tale world in which almost everyone lives to the old age.

Comment: Almost all of this question is irrelevant detail: human-like, small settlement, medieval, fantasy.  It is identical to the question "In a school of red herrings, how many eggs must hatch per 1,000 population to produce a stable population?".  And the answer is identical:  1000 ÷ life-expectancy.

Comment: I'm just going to VTC this as unclear. There are far too many details missing to be anything other than a simple division answer with the details you have provided. If you have issues providing the necessary details, picking a time period in history would provide a good analogy for your setting.

Comment: your first 3 points are exactly negating the medieval setting.

Comment: @L.Dutch technology and culture levels are not negated by these. And it is a fantasy setting as the tags show.

Comment: This is one the many questions where the word "medieval" refers to some unexplained concept in the querent's mind instead of the actual Middle Ages. How do you fancy "no major epidemic" with medieval sanitation, public health and medical knowledge? Sanitation, public health and medicine **are** technology. It was only in the 19th century that doctors realized that washing their hands before performing surgery gave their pacients vastly better chances of survival.

Comment: "Stable" in what way?   The medival population steadily grew except during the periods of massive death.

Answer (score 5):

This really is a simple math problem disguised as demography, but that said let's do the math.

First of all, we need an average lifespan for our population. Let's call the average life span 75 years, although in medieval society that's probably a bit high. What it means though is that for any given year, 1/75th of your population dies, and needs to be 'replaced'.

The question of immigration is a bit of a red herring because we can assume that unless there is a compelling advantage that your population has over surrounding populations, emigration and immigration (leavers and newcomers) would more or less even out. If not, then we need to determine the rate of imbalance, but let's for the sake of this question assume that it does indeed even out.

That makes the equation 1000/75, which is a bit over 13.

In other words, to maintain a stable population that lives (on average) to 75 years with a balanced emigration / immigration rate, you need 13 babies per 1000 population per year. In point of fact, it's better to say that you need 40 babies every 3 years as that is the balance point, but I digress.

Comment: Would the average age include child birth mortality? I would assume it would include maternal birth mortality.

Comment: @Sonvar I thought about adding that in when I wrote this, but arguably this is covered in the average lifespan. If you include infant and maternal mortality ages, then one can argue that 75 years is WAY too high an average lifespan. That might come down to as low as 40, in which case you need more babies each year (1000/40). Ultimately too it's important to note that we're talking number of babies, not number of pregnancies which in a medieval environment and higher rate of miscarriages or peri-natal mishaps, would need to be even higher.

Comment: Average life span was never a stat that seemed useful to me.  It gets thrown around a lot though when people try to push different diets or lifestyles (well-trained midwives and good sewage disposal are more important than anything else).  It also doesn't matter because the age someone dies only counts if it's 1) before having kids, 2) after having some but not all planned kids, or after having kids.

Comment: @Cyn I actually don't disagree with your assessment of the use of average life span today, but it is the most useful statistic for birth rates because it is a predictor of death rates. There are going to be decades when your population is out of balance but on average it will balance out if you take the average lifespan as the denominator under your population; that's the number of people who need to be replaced, whether they've had kids or not. Remember that we're not forcing all people to reproduce, just counting how many new kids are needed for balance.

Comment: @Cyn sometimes in statistics, certain metrics are left out for one reason or another. Infant birth mortality is usually one of those factor as some models do not contribute them to the population, since they did not survive long enough to count towards the population numbes

Comment: @Sonvar I'm aware of that.  But without stating who you're leaving out (neonates? infants? children under 5 years? etc) it's impossible to assess the stats.  75 years is a *very* high average age.  It's about that for American males today.

Answer (score 1):

Now, given that main causes of death in Medieval Europe was:

- Starvation
- Disease
- War
- Infant mortality and maternal mortality

The first three do not apply in your case, the fourth one is severely reduced by

> Magical healing for moderate illness and accidents is expensive but not out of reach of the peasants (minor ones don't require magic, major ones may have treatment but are unaffordable).

Now, you have stated that the technological level and life conditions are still medieval like, thus I would guess that we can use the 1840 as a rough estimation of the "average life expectancy". Why 1840? Because historically the Industrial Revolution had increased the condition of life, yet starvation, diseases and war was still an issue thus, IMHO, we could say that those historical conditions and your conditions should roughly equal each other.

Now, the expected duration of a human life in 1840s was about 40 years or so ([take a look here])[1](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/lifeexpectancies/articles/howhaslifeexpectancychangedovertime/2015-09-09), thus using the equation provided by Tim I would say 25 seems a reasonable number. 
But it is very hard to say in general.